# Pass value between 2 html forms in the same page

Tags: php, html, jquery

this question has been asked but I haven't found a working solution.
I have 2 forms. The first is sending datas to the database (form2). The second one is uploading a photo (form1).
I would  need to save the path of the uploaded picture and store it in a text input in form1 and after send it with the form2 datas. Do you have any tips?  It is possible without JQuery using just Php?
I have a solution with JQuery but it is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                function submitform()
                            {
                            var name=$('#name').val();
                            $('#variable').val(name);   // set the value of name field to the hidden field
                            $('form#form1').submit();   // submit the form
                            }
            </script>
```

## Create a new product

```
<form action="../handlers/processNewProduct.php" id="form2">  

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="productname" class="form-label">Product Name</label>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productname" name="productname" placeholder="Product Name">
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="description" class="form-label">Description</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" value="xxxxxxxxx" name="description" placeholder="Description">
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="pricelist" class="form-label">Price list</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="pricelist" name="pricelist" placeholder="Price">
    </div>
    <input type='text' name='variable' id='variable' value=''>
        
    <button type="" class="btn btn-primary">Insert data</button>
</form>

<form action="../handlers/processUploadProductPicture.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1" onsubmit="submitform()">
            Select image to upload:
        <input type='file' name='fileToUpload' id='name'>
        <input type='submit'  value='Upload Image' id='upload'>
</form>
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you want separate forms to handle this, instead of only one?

Comment: I thought first to process the Picture Upload (size,format jpg,.png), store the picturepath and then send everything to the database. The id_''variable" could be also an hidden input.

Comment: You can perform all those actions from a single form. There is no reason to create two steps, the order of your backend actions can easily be arranged within a single submit.

Comment: I tried...creating a single POST  form and  setting the action="processPictureorProduct"...from there I go to check the variable with an If statement  IF $_POST["uploadPicture"] or $_POST["sendToDB"]...it is working but when I Upload the picture and send data to the backend I am not able to retrieve the picturePath

Comment: I solved....everything is fine